# Wordpress Image Attachment using remote image

Tags: images, attachments

Is it possible to use remote image as wordpress attachment?
* Not stored on our server..

How about the code/script?
i see that attachment is act as post in database.. 
seems it's possible.

***UPDATE***

what i need is to programatically attach image from remote URL and the final goal is the remote image can show as attachment page template just like uploaded image. is that possible?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to get very familiar with [wp_insert_attachment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment), [download_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/download_url) and  [media_handle_sideload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload). It's a bit lengthy to get into the details here, but it absolutely can be done. I used these methods to create a media tab that allows a user to put in a vimeo/youtube URL which I store in a postmeta and use their (vimeo/youtube) automatic thumbnail endpoints to attach an image to the post representing the video.

Comment: Getting into details is what our site is about. Could you add an example?

Comment: Hi, if using download_url() it will stored in our server..

the main purpose, what i am approach is using remote image(hotlink) as post attachment and will show in attachment page template with own permalink like wp image attachment.

or maybe we can just insert remote image to postmeta?
but i don't know if it's work as attachment permalink.

Thanks

Comment: You can control how the attachment permalink is defined with the `attachment_link` filter. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L292

Answer (score 1):

You can add images trough the 'from URL' tab in the 'add media' window. Or do you mean really attaching the images with the post? In that case I would try to fix something with custom meta fields where you can add the URL's. That way it's semi-attached.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
what i need is to programatically attach image from remote URL and final goal is the remote image can show as attachment page template.

is that possible?